# Can two parallel lines meet?

Tags: differential-geometry, geometry, geodesics

My physics teacher talked about the meeting of 2 parallel lines, and he said that it may occur in the infinity or something. I know that 2 parallel lines can meet in spherical geometry, (thanks to math stackexchange), but can such a thing occur in physics? (I really want to know so I could tell him).

Comment: Stuff like "lines", "parallel", and "infinity" are mathematics. In physics they are used to *model* reality. Parallel lines do meet at infinity in projective geometries, which is probably what your teacher meant.

Comment: Maybe you're right, because last year we did math problems that are with physics, and he said it last year

Comment: Hi @Yonatan Markman: What is your definition of a "straight line" in our universe?

Comment: Voted to re-open so that someone can talk about geodesics in GR. Lest the question shouldn't be re-opened, I'll just say that in General Relativity, geodesics take the place of and are in all ways indistinguishable from straight lines, as indeed the geodesic concept applies to great circles on the sphere or  the circle / line geodesics on the hyperbolic plane or Poincaré disc. Geodesics can meet in some solutions of the Einstein field equations. It's important to understand that once one takes the parallel postulate out of "absolute geometry", one must put in its place some other postulate ...

Comment: ... to define the geometry uniquely and there are in general many ways to do this. The physical way in GR is defined through the metric and choice, in accordance with the fundamental theorem of Riemannian geometry, of the unique torsion free connexion. There are many topics in physics that can be looked at from the geometry of curved manifolds - notably the fibre bundles build in gauge theories. Anyhow, if you could rephrase your question to be more specific, and also say a little about your level, there could be some quite interesting answers.

Comment: I'm not really sure why this was closed. It looks like a good question to me.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of giving a rather trivial answer to a complicated question, [gravitational lensing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) seems to me an obvious way parallel lines (using any reasonable definition of parallel) can meet, and we have found lots of examples of gravitational lenses. If you Google image search for *gravitational lens* you'll find many images showing how this happens. [This seems a nice illustration](http://www.dlr.de/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-5089/8554_read-18007/), though you'll find many others.